# In bash, how could I add integers with leading zeroes and maintain a specified buffer

Tags: bash, shell, output-formatting

For example, I want to count from 001 to 100. Meaning the zero buffer would start off with 2, 1, then eventually 0 when it reaches 100 or more.

ex:
001
002
...
010
011
...
098
099
100

I could do this if the numbers had a predefined number of zeroes with printf "%02d" $i. But that's static and not dynamic and would not work in my example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Be sure to select the answer (via the checkmark) that you feel best resolves your question so others can benefit from the knowledge put forth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to zero pad a sequence of integers in bash so that all have the same width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If by static versus dynamic you mean that you'd like to be able to use a variable for the width, you can do this:

```
$ padtowidth=3
$ for i in 0 {8..11} {98..101}; do printf "%0*d\n" $padtowidth $i; done
000
008
009
010
011
098
099
100
101
```

The asterisk is replaced by the value of the variable it corresponds to in the argument list (`$padtowidth` in this case).

Otherwise, the only reason your example doesn't work is that you use "2" (perhaps as if it were the maximum padding to apply) when it should be "3" (as in my example) since that value is the resulting total width (not the pad-only width).

Comment: Yes, you're probably right about using zsh in a bash script. I overlooked your method. Yours and SiegeX work great for what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

If your system has it, try `seq` with the `-w` (`--equal-width`) option:

```
$ seq -s, -w 1 10
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10

$ for i in `seq -w 95 105` ; do echo -n " $i" ; done
095 096 097 098 099 100 101 102 103 104 105
```

Comment: This is a good idea but not exactly how i was envisioning it. It'll buffer with 3 zeroes if and only if it reaches an integer with 3 digits (ex: 100). If it reaches just 99, it'll only include a buffer with 2 zeroes. Sorry I wasn't specific.

Comment: Johannes. Yes you are right. This method works correctly as well. I don't know what I was running yesterday.Thanks.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the right answer. Most elegant solution. :) Thanks mob!

Answer (score 15):

In Bash version 4 (use bash -version) you can use [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion). Putting a `0` before either limit forces the numbers to be padded by zeros

```
echo {01..100} # 001 002 003 ...
echo {03..100..3} # 003 006 009 ...
```

Comment: That requires Bash 4. Earlier versions don't do padding in brace expansions.

Comment: Thanks Johannes and Dennis. Yes, I found that this requires bash 4. Which i don't use. I found though I can use zsh in the same fashion. 

for i in $(zsh -c "echo {$FROM..$TO}")do echo $i;done 

Works fine and didn't have to script anything overly complicated.

Comment: @readdit: Calling zsh from a bash script seems rather wasteful. Either write the whole script in zsh (it has a high level of Bash compatibility, although some things are different enough that you'll have to make a few modifications) or use built in features of bash such as the printf technique I show in my answer. There are other techniques that will also work using only shell builtins.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/bash

max=100; 

for ((i=1;i<=$max;i++)); do 
    printf "%0*d\n" ${#max} $i
done
```

The code above will auto-pad your numbers with the correct number of 0's based upon how many digits the max/terminal value contains.  All you need to do is change the `max` variable and it will handle the rest.

Examples:

#### max=10

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

#### max=100

```
001
002
003
004
005
006
...
097
098
099
100
```

#### max=1000

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
...
0997
0998
0999
1000
```

Answer (score 4):

```
# jot is available on FreeBSD, Mac OS X, ...    
jot -s " " -w '%03d' 5   
jot -s " " -w '%03d' 10  
jot -s " " -w '%03d' 50  
jot -s " " -w '%03d' 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pad values up to a variable number with variable padding:

```
$values_count=514;
$padding_width=5;

for i in 0 `seq 1 $(($values_count - 1))`; do printf "%0*d\n" $padding_width $i; done;
```

This would print out 00000, 00001, ... 00513.
(I didn't find any of the current answers meeting my need)

Answer (score 0):

To complement @DennisWilliamson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3192254/7200293):

`seq`'s `-f` parameter is a possible way to achieve the same:

```
$ seq -f "%03g" 1 100
001
002
003
...
098
099
100
```

Here, `3` sets the number of digits to pad with leading zeros as necessary, and can be set to any positive integer. This might require a sufficiently recent version of `seq`, though. See @AminAbbaspour's [answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21570804/7200293), who the credit goes to.

Above output could be used in both `echo` (if its before-mentioned [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) isn't an option) and `printf`, as well, if necessary. E.g.:

```
$ for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 100); do echo "file-${i}.log"; done
file-001.log
file-002.log
file-003.log
...
file-098.log
file-099.log
file-100.log
```

Of course, for such simple cases, the detour via `for` loop and `printf`/`echo` might be overkill – `seq` alone can produce the same output:

```
seq -f "file-%03g.log" 1 100
```