# Adding a zero to single digit variable

Tags: bash, unix, variables, directory

Trying to add a zero before the varaible if it's less than 10 and create said directory. I can't seem to get the zero to add correctly. Keeps resulting in making `02.1.2011`, `02.2.2011` etc,etc.

```
i=0
for i in {01..31}
do
    if $i > 10
        then
            mkdir $path/02.0$i.2011
        else    
            mkdir $path/02.$i.2011
    fi
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to zero pad a sequence of integers in bash so that all have the same width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width)

Comment: See how to zero-padding with parameter expansion: https://askubuntu.com/a/1257316/670392

Answer (score 66):

You can replace the whole lot with:

```
for day in 0{1..9} {10..31} ; do
    mkdir ${path}/02.${day}.2011
done
```

while still not having to start up any external processes (other than what may be in the loop body).

That's probably not that important *here* since `mkdir` is not one of those things you tend to do a lot of in a tight loop but it *will* be important if you write a lot of your quick and dirty code in `bash`.

Process creation is expensive when you're doing it hundreds of thousands of times as some of my scripts have occasionally done :-)

Example so you can see it in action:

```
pax$ for day in 0{8..9} {10..11}; do echo ${day}; done
08
09
10
11
```

And, if you have a recent-enough version of `bash`, it will honor your request for leading digits:

> A sequence expression takes the form `{x..y[..incr]}`, where `x` and `y` are either integers or single characters, and `incr`, an optional increment, is an integer.
>
> When integers are supplied, the expression expands to each number between `x` and `y`, inclusive.
>
> Supplied integers may be prefixed with `0` to force each term to have the same width. When either `x` or `y` begins with a zero, the shell attempts to force all generated terms to contain the same number of digits, zero-padding where necessary.

So, on my Debian 6 box, with `bash` version 4.1.5:

```
pax$ for day in {08..11} ; do echo ${day} ; done
08
09
10
11
```

Comment: Bonus for the comment about more recent bash versions supporting leading zeros!

Comment: For some reason, my bash 5.0.7 installation via macports doesn't support prefixing with 0. But specifying multiple non-consecutive increments is amazing.

Answer (score 32):

You can use

```
$(printf %02d $i)
```

To generate the numbers with the format you want.

```
for i in $(seq 0 1 31)
do
    mkdir $path/02.$(printf %02d $i).2011
done
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about seq. But just `seq 31` would do the trick, I think. OP didn't want 0 and the default for both `first` and `increment` is 1.

Comment: `seq -w` generates numbers with leading zeros.

Comment: Nice that it is easy to integrate into old echo statements like `echo "this is a $var" `-> `echo "this is a $(printf %03d $var)"`

Answer (score 16):

Better:

```
for i in $(seq -f %02g 1 31)
do
    mkdir "$path/02.$i.2011"
done
```

Or even:

```
for i in {01..31}
do
    mkdir "$path/02.$(printf "%02d" $i).2011"
done
```

Comment: adding another digit to the curly braces did it!

Answer (score 6):

In Bash 4, brace range expansions will give you leading zeros if you ask for them:

```
for i in {01..31}
```

without having to do anything else.

If you're using earlier versions of Bash (or 4, for that matter) there's no need to use an external utility such as `seq`:

```
for i in {1..31}
```

or

```
for ((i=1; i<=31; i++))
```

with either of those:

```
mkdir "$path/02.$(printf '%02d' "$i").2011"
```

You can also do:

```
z='0'
mkdir "$path/02.${z: -${#i}}$i.2011"
```

Using paxdiablo's suggestion, you can make all the directories at once ***without a loop***:

```
mkdir "$path"/02.{0{1..9},{10..31}}.2011
```

Answer (score 3):

Will this work for you?

```
zeroes="0000000"
pad=$zeroes$i
echo ${pad:(-2)}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ seq --version | head -1
seq (GNU coreutils) 8.21
$ seq -f "%02g" 1 10
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using equal-width option (`-w`) in `seq` command:

```sh
for i in `seq -w 1 31`; do echo $i; done
```

It returns:

```
01
02
03
...
31
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if/then statement is backwards.  You are adding a 0 when it is a above 10, not adding one when it is below.

Another bug is that you make the cutoff strictly greater than 10, which does not include 10, even though 10 is two digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
path=/tmp
ruby -rfileutils -e '1.upto(31){|x| FileUtils.mkdir "'$path'/02.%02d.2011" % x}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did for a script where I'm asking for a day, range of days, regex, etc. with a default to the improved regexes shared by paxdiablo.

```
for day in $days
    do if [ 1 -eq "${#day}"] ; then
        day="0$day"
    fi
```

I just run through this at the beginning of my loop where I run a bunch of log analysis on the day in question, buried in directories with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

I created this simple utility to perform this, Good Luck , hope this helps stack'ers!!

```
for i in {1..24}
do
charcount=`echo $i|wc -m`
count=`expr $charcount - 1`
if [ $count -lt 2 ];
then
i="0`echo $i`"
fi
echo "$i"
done
```