# How can I increment a number in a while-loop while preserving leading zeroes (BASH < V4)

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a BASH script that downloads some transcripts of a podcast with cURL. All transcript files have a name that only differs by three digits: `filename[three-digits].txt`

- from `filename001.txt`
- to.... `filename440.txt`.

I store the three digits as a number in a variable and increment the variable in a while loop. How can I increment the number without it losing its leading zeroes?

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

# [...] code for handling storage

episode=001
last=440

secnow_transcript_url="https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-"
last_token=".txt"

while [ $episode -le $last ]; do
    curl -X GET $secnow_transcript_url$episode$last_token > # storage location
    episode=$[$episode+001];
    sleep 60 # Don't stress the server too much!
done
```

---

I searched a lot and [discovered nice approaches of others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460123/bash-for-loop-echo-leading-zero), that do solve my problem, but **out of curiosity I would love to know if there is solution to my problem that keeps the while-loop**, despite a for-loop would be more appropriate in the first place, as I know the range, but the day will come, when I will need a while loop! :-)

```
#!/bin/bash
for episode in $(seq -w 01 05); do
    curl -X GET $secnow_transcript_url$episode$last_token > # ...
done
```

[or for just a few digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099119/adding-a-zero-to-single-digit-variable) (becomes unpractical for more digits)

```
#!/bin/bash
for episode in 00{1..9} 0{10..99} {100..440}; do
    curl -X GET $secnow_transcript_url$episode$last_token > # ...
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$((10#$n))` to remove zero padding (and do calculations), and `printf` to add zero padding back. Here are both put together to increment a zero padded number in a while loop:

```
n="0000123"
digits=${#n} # number of digits, here calculated from the original number
while sleep 1
do
    n=$(printf "%0${digits}d\n" "$((10#$n + 1))")
    echo "$n"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful code, I learned a damn lot through these 7 lines.

Answer (score 1):

`for ep in {001..440}` should work.

But, as you want a while loop: let printf handle leading zeroes

```
while (( episode <= last )); do
    printf -v url "%s%03d%s" $secnow_transcript_url $episode $last_token
    curl -X GET $url > # storage location
    (( episode++ ))
    sleep 60 # Don't stress the server too much!
done
```

Comment: That does not work for me as it url becomes `... 8000 
9000 
10000 
11000 ...`

Comment: Nevertheless, I also learned some syntax through you. The -v parameter of printf was new to me and also the dollar-sign free syntax. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for dealing with padding only on _output_ (therefore, the start/end values should also be unpadded - i.e., `episode=1` - as a padded value such as `010` could get you in trouble); note that bash versions < 4 (e.g., on OS X 10.9) do _not_ support padding in brace expansion, so that `{001..440}` yields `1 2 ...` rather than `001 002 ...`.

Comment: @th3m3s: The dollar-sign free syntax is called arithmetic evaluation  (`((...))` - as a Boolean test) / arithmetic expansion (`$((...))` - as an expression returning a value) and the latter should be used instead of the deprecated `$[...]` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
zi=000000000$i
s=${zi:(-3)}
echo $s
```

Comment: The problem of my code is, that it removes the leading zeroes after the first incrementation, so that this happens: `001 2 3 ... 10 11 ... 101 102 ...`. I don't need to strip leading zeroes, but nevertheless I have learned through you, that I can read a variable from the rear, thanks.

Comment: Use a simple integer (i) for increment operation, and use the padded integer (s) for GET operation.