# How to zero pad a sequence of integers in bash so that all have the same width?

Tags: bash, numbers, padding

I need to loop some values,

```
for i in $(seq $first $last)
do
    does something here
done
```

For `$first` and `$last`, I need it to be of fixed length 5. So if the input is `1`, I need to add zeros in front such that it becomes `00001`. It loops till `99999` for example, but the length has to be 5.

E.g.: `00002`, `00042`, `00212`, `12312` and so forth.

Any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: A good answer could be: seq - w 1 99999. Option -w keeps output lenght constant, padding shortest numbers with 0.

Comment: Also rename files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754/bash-script-to-pad-file-names

Comment: Many answers here recommend `for variable in $(something to generate the numbers); do ...` but this is problematic when the list of numbers is long. It is much more efficient to use `something to generate the numbers | while read -r variable; do ...`. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor which discusses reading lines from files etc, but some of the arguments apply here too.

Comment: See how to zero-padding with parameter expansion: https://askubuntu.com/a/1257316/670392

Answer (score 989, accepted):

In your specific case though it's probably easiest to use the `-f` flag to `seq` to get it to format the numbers as it outputs the list.  For example:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 10 15)
do
  echo $i
done
```

will produce the following output:

```
00010
00011
00012
00013
00014
00015
```

More generally, `bash` has `printf` as a built-in so you can pad output with zeroes as follows:

```
$ i=99
$ printf "%05d\n" $i
00099
```

You can use the `-v` flag to store the output in another variable:

```
$ i=99
$ printf -v j "%05d" $i
$ echo $j
00099
```

Notice that `printf` supports a slightly different format to `seq` so you need to use `%05d` instead of `%05g`.

Comment: `%05g` instead of `%05d` fixed it for me.  _"00026"_ was giving me _"00022"_.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, comprehensive answer.
One small correction: strictly speaking, `seq` supports a _subset_ of the format chars. that `printf` supports (and that subsets includes `g`, but not `d`).
The behavior of characters `d` and `g` differs subtly in that `d` interprets `0`-prefixed numbers strings as _octal_ numbers and converts them to decimal, whereas `g` treats them as decimals. (@EdManet: that's why '00026' turned into '00022' with `d`).
Another thing worth mentioning: `seq -w` does _automatic_ zero-padding of the output numbers based on the widest number generated.

Comment: This helped me generate hex characters list. `for (( i = 0; i <= 0xffffffff; i++ )) do printf "%08x\n" $i ; done >> hex.txt` produced a 8 character hexadecimal list. Thanks.

Comment: `seq --help`: "FORMAT must be suitable for printing one argument of type 'double';
it defaults to %.PRECf if FIRST, INCREMENT, and LAST are all fixed point
decimal numbers with maximum precision PREC, and to %g otherwise." The possible [conversion specifiers](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/man-pages/printf.3.en#Conversion_specifiers) are [`efgaEFGA`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v8.31/src/seq.c#L261-L263).

Comment: this is significantly slower than the `-w` option that seq provides. and because it passes the number through printf, if you're not running the GNU versions (i.e. running mac native versions), you'll end up with scientific notation for larger numbers (roughly any ints > 6 digits will be in the x.xxxxxxe+0y format)

Answer (score 207):

Easier still you can just do

```
for i in {00001..99999}; do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: This works on Bash version 4.1.2 (CentOS 6) but fails in version 3.2.25 (CentOS 5). I do agree that this is much more aesthetically pleasing way to do it!

Comment: Works, but does not give zero padded strings on my bash

Comment: On a Mac (Bash 4.4), this doesn't pad the numbers. On CentOS & SuSE, it works great!

Comment: This works fine on macOS with Bash `4.4.23(1)-release`

Comment: Note: If you're looping in order to run a command, and your command can accept multiple arguments, you might be better off running the command directly. e.g. It takes around 7 seconds for my computer to loop through `for i in {0001..9000}; do; touch $i; done;`, but is almost instant (and less code) if I just do: `touch {0001..9000}`

Answer (score 144):

If the end of sequence has maximal length of padding (for example, if you want 5 digits and command is `seq 1 10000`), than you can use `-w` flag for seq - it adds padding itself.

```
seq -w 1 10
```

would produce

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer. Why does it have so few upvotes? 

Comment: easy, because the padding depends on the max number you want to reach. If this is a parameter you never know beforehand how many zero you will end up with

Comment: This doesn't give a specified fixed length, just results which are all of the _same_ length.

Comment: You can also do `seq -w 001 009` to force length 3.

Comment: fresh seq installed in macOS does not have possiblity to do `seq -w 001 009`, so you are lucky it works for you

Comment: @m_messiah: The gnu  version of seq  on mac, installed with brew, from "coreutils" and available as `gseq`,  works as mention by @isarandi, just the built-in bsd variant is too simple...

Answer (score 117):

use printf with "%05d" e.g.

```
printf "%05d" 1
```

Answer (score 30):

Very simple using `printf`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] printf "%05d\n" 1
00001
[jaypal:~/Temp] printf "%05d\n" 2
00002
```

Answer (score 14):

Use awk like this:

```
awk -v start=1 -v end=10 'BEGIN{for (i=start; i<=end; i++) printf("%05d\n", i)}'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006
00007
00008
00009
00010
```

**Update:**

As pure bash alternative you can do this to get same output:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
   printf "%05d\n" $i
done
```

This way you can *avoid* using an external program `seq` which is **NOT available** on all the flavors of *nix.

Answer (score 12):

I pad output with more digits (zeros) than I need then use tail to only use the number of digits I am looking for. Notice that you have to use '6' in tail to get the last five digits :)

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
RESULT=$(echo 00000$i | tail -c 6)
echo $RESULT
done
```

Comment: If you wanted to use the correct number of places in the -c argument of tail, you could use 'echo -n 00000$i' as this stops it outputting a newline which is one of the chars tail is returning, hence it needing to be one higher in this answer. Depending what you're then doing, the newline, if left, might affect the results.

Comment: Using an external process to trim the variable in the loop is rather inefficient. You can use the shell's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) features instead. In Bash there is a facility for extracting a particular substring by index, or you can use the prefix and suffix substitutions with a pattern which matches the desired width, though it requires a bit of back-and-forth.

Answer (score 10):

If you want N digits, add 10^N and delete the first digit.

```
for (( num=100; num<=105; num++ ))
do
  echo ${num:1:3}
done
```

Output:

```
01
02
03
04
05
```

Answer (score 6):

Other way :

```
zeroos="000"
echo 

for num in {99..105};do
 echo ${zeroos:${#num}:${#zeroos}}${num}
done
```

So simple function to convert any number would be:

```
function leading_zero(){

    local num=$1
    local zeroos=00000
    echo ${zeroos:${#num}:${#zeroos}}${num} 

}
```

Comment: if the number **must not** have more than 3 digits, i would recommend the first variant with the `temp_num` from https://askubuntu.com/a/1257316/354350. **||** although i personally prefer `echo ${zeroos:0:-${#num}}${num}` like mentioned in "**Note 1**".

Answer (score 6):

One way without using external process forking is string manipulation, in a generic case it would look like this:

```sh
#start value
CNT=1

for [whatever iterative loop, seq, cat, find...];do
   # number of 0s is at least the amount of decimals needed, simple concatenation
   TEMP="000000$CNT"
   # for example 6 digits zero padded, get the last 6 character of the string
   echo ${TEMP:(-6)}
   # increment, if the for loop doesn't provide the number directly
   TEMP=$(( TEMP + 1 ))
done
```

This works quite well on WSL as well, where forking is a really heavy operation. I had a 110000 files list, using `printf "%06d" $NUM` took over 1 minute, the solution above ran in about 1 second.

Comment: unfortunately my suggested edit to change the last line of the loop `TEMP=$(( TEMP + 1 ))` to `CNT=$(( CNT + 1 ))` got rejected, although  increasing `TEMP` instead of `CNT` makes no sense! ...because `TEMP` gets overwritten with `0000001` at the beginning of the loop, you'll get an infinite loop.

Comment: beyond that, this answer (especially `echo ${TEMP:(-6)}`) is perfectly fine! - although [there are also slightly different variants](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257316/354350) which may be a little bit more appropriate for different use cases.

Answer (score 3):

This will work also:

```
for i in {0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're just after padding numbers with zeros to achieve fixed length, just add the nearest multiple of 10
eg. for 2 digits, add 10^2, then remove the first 1 before displaying output.

This solution works to pad/format single numbers of any length, or a whole sequence of numbers using a for loop.

```
# Padding 0s zeros:
# Pure bash without externals eg. awk, sed, seq, head, tail etc.
# works with echo, no need for printf

pad=100000      ;# 5 digit fixed

for i in {0..99999}; do ((j=pad+i))
    echo ${j#?}
done
```

Tested on Mac OSX 10.6.8, Bash ver 3.2.48

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

```
$ seq 1 10 | awk '{printf("%05d\n", $1)}'
```

**Input(Pattern 1. Slow):**

```
$ seq 1 10 | xargs -n 1 printf "%05d\n"
```

**Input(Pattern 2. Fast):**

```
$ seq 1 10 | awk '{printf("%05d\n", $1)}'
```

**Output(same result in each case):**

```
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006
00007
00008
00009
00010
```

**Explanation**

I'd like to suggest the above patterns. These implementations can be used as a command so that we can use them again with ease. All you have to care about in these commands is the length of the numbers after being converted.(like changing the number `%05d` into `%09d`.) Plus, it's also applicable to other solutions such as the following. The example is too dependent on my environment, so your output might be different, but I think you can tell the usefulness easily.

```
$ wc -l * | awk '{printf("%05d\n", $1)}'
00007
00001
00001
00001
00013
00017
00001
00001
00001
00043
```

And like this:

```
$ wc -l * | awk '{printf("%05d\n", $1)}' | sort | uniq
00001
00007
00013
00017
00043
```

Moreover, if you write in this manner, we can also execute the commands asynchronously. (I found a nice article:
https://www.dataart.com/en/blog/linux-pipes-tips-tricks)

disclaimer: I'm not sure of this, and I am not a *nix expert.

**Performance test:**

Super Slow:

```
$ time seq 1 1000 | xargs -n 1 printf "%09d\n" > test
seq 1 1000  0.00s user 0.00s system 48% cpu 0.008 total
xargs -n 1 printf "%09d\n" > test  1.14s user 2.17s system 84% cpu 3.929 total
```

Relatively Fast:

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
   printf "%09d\n" $i
done
$ time sh k.sh > test
sh k.sh > test  0.01s user 0.01s system 74% cpu 0.021 total


for i in {1..1000000}
do
   printf "%09d\n" $i
done
$ time sh k.sh > test
sh k.sh > test  7.10s user 1.52s system 99% cpu 8.669 total
```

Fast:

```
$ time seq 1 1000 | awk '{printf("%09d\n", $1)}' > test
seq 1 1000  0.00s user 0.00s system 47% cpu 0.008 total
awk '{printf("%09d\n", $1)}' > test  0.00s user 0.00s system 52% cpu 0.009 total


$ time seq 1 1000000 | awk '{printf("%09d\n", $1)}' > test
seq 1 1000000  0.27s user 0.00s system 28% cpu 0.927 total
awk '{printf("%09d\n", $1)}' > test  0.92s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.937 total
```

If you have to implement the higher performance solution, probably it may require other techniques, not using the shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the `seq -w` answers with @tripleee 's comment on the question, you can do the following:

```bash
seq -w 1 1000 | while read -r i; do
    echo $i
done
```

As explained in the article @tripleee [linked](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), this will read a single a single number from the pipe at a time, rather than loading the whole sequence into memory at once.

Note that I can't see any meaningful difference in speed compared to the for loop version, or the `{0000..1000}` version.

### Can you avoid looping?

If you're doing this to run a command which can accept multiple arguments, it may be faster to run the command directly using multiple arguments and brace expansion than looping.

For example, on my system it takes 7 seconds to run the following loop:

```
for i in {0001..9001}; do; touch $i; done
```

But the following runs almost instantly:

```
touch {0001..9001}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `awk` for that — either `seq` or `jot` alone suffices :

```
% seq -f '%05.f' 6     # bsd-seq
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006

% gseq -f '%05.f' 6    # gnu-seq
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006

% jot -w '%05.f' 6
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006
```

…… unless you're going into bigint territory :

```
% gawk -Mbe '

  function __(_,___) {
      return +_<+___?___:_
  }
  BEGIN {
        _+=_^=_<_                 
      ____="%0*.f\n"   
  } {                      
       ___=__($--_, !+$++_)                
     _____=__(++_+--_, length(______=+$NF)) 
     do {                     
        printf(____,_____,___)
     }  while (___++<______) 
                                                       
  }' <<< '999999999999999999996 1000000000000000000003'

0999999999999999999996
0999999999999999999997
0999999999999999999998
0999999999999999999999
1000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000001
1000000000000000000002
1000000000000000000003
```

——————————————————————————————————————————————————

If you need to print out a *HUGE* range of numbers, then this approach maybe a bit faster -

- printing out every integer from 1 to 1 million, left-zero-padded to 9-digits wide, in `0.049s`
- ****caveat*** : I didn't have the spare time to make it cover all input ranges :: it's just a proof of concept accepting increments of powers of 10

——————————————————————————————————————————————————

```
 ( time ( LC_ALL=C mawk2 '
 
   function jot(____,_______,_____,_,__,___,______) {
       if(____==(____^!____)) {
           return +____<+_______\
               ? sprintf("%0*.f",_______,____)\
               : +____ 
        }
        _______= (_______-=____=length(____)-\
                 (_=!(_<_)))<+_ \
                 ? "" \
                 : sprintf("%0*.f",_______,!_)
           __=_= (!(__=_+=_+_))(__=(-+--_)+(__+=_)^++_)\
                 (__+=_=(((_--^_--+_++)^++_-_^!_)/_))(__+_)
          _____= "."
     gsub(_____,"\\&&",__)
     ____—-
     do { 
         gsub(_____,__,_)
        _____=_____"." 
     } while(—____)

     gsub(_____,(_______)"&\n",_)
     sub("^[^\n]+[\n]","",_)
     sub(".$",""~"",_______)
     
     return \
     (_)(_______)\
     sprintf("%0*.f",length(_____),__<__)

   } { print jot($1,$2) }' <<< '10000000 9'
  
 ) | pvE9 ) |xxh128sum |ggXy3 | lgp3

 sleep 2
 ( time ( LC_ALL=C jot 1000000 | 
          LC_ALL=C mawk2 '{ printf("%09.f\n", $1) }' 
 
 ) | pvE9 ) |xxh128sum |ggXy3 | lgp3


     out9: 9.54MiB 0:00:00 [ 275MiB/s] [ 275MiB/s] [<=> ]
( LC_ALL=C mawk2  <<< '1000000 9'; )

0.04s user 0.01s system 93% cpu 0.049 total

e0491043bdb4c8bc16769072f3b71f98  stdin


     out9: 9.54MiB 0:00:00 [36.5MiB/s] [36.5MiB/s] [  <=> ]
( LC_ALL=C jot 1000000 | LC_ALL=C mawk2 '{printf("%09.f\n", $1)}'; )

0.43s user 0.01s system 158% cpu 0.275 total

e0491043bdb4c8bc16769072f3b71f98  stdin
```

By the time you're doing 10 million, the time differences become noticeable :

```
 out9: 95.4MiB 0:00:00 [ 216MiB/s] [ 216MiB/s] [<=> ]
 ( LC_ALL=C mawk2  <<< '10000000 9'; )

 0.38s user 0.06s system 95% cpu 0.458 total

 be3ed6c8e9ee947e5ba4ce51af753663  stdin


 out9: 95.4MiB 0:00:02 [36.3MiB/s] [36.3MiB/s] [ <=> ]
 ( LC_ALL=C jot 10000000 | LC_ALL=C mawk2 '{printf("%09.f\n", $1)}'; )

 4.30s user 0.04s system 164% cpu 2.638 total
 
 be3ed6c8e9ee947e5ba4ce51af753663  stdin




 out9: 95.4MiB 0:00:02 [35.2MiB/s] [35.2MiB/s] [ <=> ]

 ( LC_ALL=C python3 -c '__=1; ___=10**7;

   [ print("{0:09d}".format(_)) for _ in range(__,___+__) ]' 

 ) | pvE9 ) | xxh128sum |ggXy3 | lgp3 ;  )

 2.68s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 2.725 total
 
 be3ed6c8e9ee947e5ba4ce51af753663  stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create a sequence of numbers 'seq' from 1 to 1000, and fix the width '-w' (width is determined by length of ending number, in this case 4 digits for 1000).

2.) Also, select which numbers you want using 'sed -n' (in this case, we select numbers 1-100).

3.) 'echo' out each number. Numbers are stored in the variable 'i', accessed using the '$'.

Pros: This code is pretty clean.

Cons: 'seq' isn't native to all Linux systems (as I understand)

```
for i in `seq -w 1 1000 | sed -n '1,100p'`; 
do 
    echo $i; 
done
```