# Range with leading zero in bash

Tags: bash

How to add leading zero to bash range?
For example, I need cycle 01,02,03,..,29,30
How can I implement this using bash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zero Padding In Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/zero-padding-in-bash)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

another **seq** trick will work:

```
 seq -w 30
```

if you check the man page, you will see the -w option is exactly for your requirement:

```
-w, --equal-width
              equalize width by padding with leading zeroes
```

Answer (score 27):

In recent versions of bash you can do:

```
echo {01..30}
```

Output:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Or if it should be comma separated:

```
echo {01..30} | tr ' ' ','
```

Which can also be accomplished with [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
a=$(echo {01..30})
echo ${a// /,}
```

Output:

```
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use seq's format option:

```
seq -f "%02g" 30
```

Answer (score 3):

A "pure bash" way would be something like this:

```
echo {0..2}{0..9}
```

This will give you the following:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

Removing the first 00 and adding the last 30 is not too hard!

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it doesn't work easily when you need a range like 000--135. There is no easy way to stop at 135.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
printf " %02d" $(seq 1 30)
```