# Pass range to bash for loop and generate output using leading zeroes

Tags: bash

I'm trying to produce a rather simple bash script with a single `for` loop whose range should be passed when calling it.

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {$1..$2}
  do
    file=file_$i.txt
    echo $file
  done
```

which I call using: `./my_script.sh 01 06`.

The output I'm after is:

```
file_01.txt
file_02.txt
file_03.txt
file_04.txt
file_05.txt
file_06.txt
```

(notice that there's a leading `0`, *this is important*) but what I get with the above script is:

```
file_{01..20}.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Range with leading zero in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376396/range-with-leading-zero-in-bash)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash)

Comment: I don't think my question is a duplicate of neither of those posts. It's rather an amalgamation of the questions in both. Thanks for pointing me to them, I'll try to combine them into a single answer.

Comment: Do you want trailing or leading zeros?

Comment: Gah it's leading, thanks for bringing my attention to that @Cyrus! Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the answers in the questions [Range with leading zero in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376396/range-with-leading-zero-in-bash) and [How do I iterate over a range of numbers defined by variables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169511/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-range-of-numbers-defined-by-variables-in-bash) (thanks timrau & Ziyao Wei for pointing me to them) I got:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq -w $1 $2)
  do
    file=file_$i.txt
    echo $file
  done
```

which outputs exactly what I needed.