# Naming files in certain way using Bash script

Tags: bash

I am running a genetic algorithm for multiple seed values and for each run I want to put the seed value in the name of the output file. I have been able to do that using the following Bash script.

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 # Multi-seed script
  3 
  4 seed=0.01
  5 for count in {1..100..1} 
  6   do echo "$seed"
  7   ./nsga2r $seed < input_data/truss.in
  8   $(mv all_pop.out all_pop_seed"$count".out)
  9   seed=$(echo "$seed+0.01" | bc)
 10 done
```

The script if very straight forward. Line-5 runs the loop for 100 `seed` values. Line-7 runs the program `nsga2r` for current seed value taking input values from file `input_data/truss.in`. Line-8 adds the current seed value to the name of the output file of current `seed` value. This yields the output as :

```
all_pop_seed1.out
all_pop_seed2.out
all_pop_seed3.out
... 
all_pop_seed10.out
all_pop_seed11.out
...
all_pop_seed99.out
all_pop_seed100.out
```

BUT how do I name them like the following instead?

```
all_pop_seed001.out
all_pop_seed002.out
all_pop_seed003.out
... 
all_pop_seed010.out
all_pop_seed011.out
...
all_pop_seed099.out
all_pop_seed100.out
```

Although this minor difference from my desired output filenames does not hinder my further analysis, still I would like to know.

Comment: so you want to be able to format `3` as `003`. do you see how you can formulate the question in a single line? reduce the problem to its minimal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `printf` to format the file name. Also, you don't need the command substitution to execute the `mv` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Multi-seed script

seed=0.01
for count in {1..100..1} ; do
  echo "$seed"
  ./nsga2r $seed < input_data/truss.in
  printf -v fname "all_pop_seed%03d.out" "$count"
  mv all_pop.out "$fname"
  seed=$(echo "$seed+0.01" | bc)
done
```

Answer (score 1):

See [How to zero pad a sequence of integers in bash so that all have the same width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/zero-padding-in-bash)

```
printf "%03d" 99
```

will produce 099
for example