# Incremental command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that I use to call a c++ program, each time indicating a different file name (see below). At present the file number is not increasing; do you have any suggestion on how to change that? Thanks!

```
for i in {0..48}; do
    ./program file$05i.jpeg
done
```

Comment: how your files will look like?

Comment: you should use $i instead of $05i.

Comment: Were you trying to get a padded five digit number there?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes that was the idea

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes that was the idea

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes that was the idea

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with the description of what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you mean this,

```
for i in {0..48}; do
    ./program file05$i.jpeg
done
```

This will execute `file050.jpeg`, `file051.jpeg` upto 48.

**Update:**

```
for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 0 48); do
    ./program file$i.jpeg
done
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8789815/3297613)

Comment: Hi Avinash, the files I need to execute are named `file00001.jpeg`, `file00002.jpeg` up to `file00048.jpeg`

Comment: Thanks that works! What if the filename is like `file00001_000.jpeg`?

Comment: `./program file$i*.jpeg`