# Add preceding zeros to all lines in a file

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, sh, padding

I have a simple text file containing some random number on every line. I wish to add preceding zeros for numbers which are less in digits.
Is there a way to do this on command line (UNIX)

Input File:

```
235
25
1
963258
45
1356924
```

Output file:

```
0000235
0000025
0000001
0963258
0000045
1356924
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk` - `printf`:

```
$ cat testfile
235
25
1
963258
45
1356924
$ awk '{printf("%07d\n", $1)}' testfile  # %07d to pad 0s.
0000235
0000025
0000001
0963258
0000045
1356924
```

Comment: @databIte, Something likes this? `echo $variable | awk '{printf("%07d\n", $1)}'`

Comment: very important: `echo "$variable"` (with quotes)

Answer (score 2):

The largest number of digits in the shown example is 7. With input file `nums.txt`

```
perl -ne 'printf("%07d\n", $_)' nums.txt > padded_nums.txt
```

> cat padded_nums.txt

```
0000235
0000025
0000001
0963258
0000045
1356924
```

---

If the number of digits of the largest number is in fact not known, a bit more is needed

```
perl -ne 'push @l, $_; }{ $lm = length( (sort {$b <=> $a} @l)[0] ); printf "%0${lm}d\n", $_ for @l' nums.txt
```

Prints the same.

As noted by [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) in comments, using the `List::Util` module gives us a maximum in `O(n)`, as opposed to `sort` with `O(nlog(n))`. This does load a module, albeit it being very light.

```
perl -MList::Util=max -ne ' ... $lm = length(max @l); ...'
```

---

Per request in a comment, here is how to pad numbers in shell, **copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width)**

```
for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 10 15)
do
  echo $i
done
```

Also, in the same answer, a single `printf` formatting is offered

```
$ i=99
$ printf "%05d\n" $i
00099
```

*Note the difference above, of `05g` vs `05d` between `seq` and `printf`.*

Here is a way to process the whole file with `bash`, **used from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash).**

```
while read p; do
  printf "%07d\n" $p
done < nums.txt
```

Finally, use `size=${#var}` to find the length of a string in `bash`, if the length of the largest number is not known. This requires two passes over data, to find the max length and then to print with it.

These examples are for `bash` but `tcsh` has all these facilities as well, used with different syntax.

Comment: `use List::Util qw(max); $lm = length(max @l)` should be more efficient than `sort`.

Comment: @glennjackman  Yes, for me it is, and I considered it.  But I thought better keep it as standard as possible, and parenthesis may be clearer outside of Perl?  The second example can in fact use the string comparison as well, so it's just `(sort @l)[-1]`, but I didn't want to go there.

Comment: max does *not* need to sort, that's the gain: max -> O(n) ; sort -> O(n log n)

Comment: @glennjackman  Right, but of course, it doesn't need to produce a sorted list.  Thank you, adding to the answer.  That does still leave the loading of another module.  It'd be interesting for me to see how that compares in the end, with very small data sets.

Comment: I did a quick benchmark with a file containing one million random numbers: reading the data, using List::Util and finding the max took about 0.4 sec; reading the data and sorting took about 1.6 sec. For one hundred random numbers: max->0.013s, sort->0.006s

Comment: @Yup, interesting!  One has to pay even with such a tight module. Given the complexity difference I guess they'd be around within 100k range or so.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash:

```
# read the numbers from the file into an array
mapfile -t nums < file

# find the maximum length
maxlen=0
for n in "${nums[@]}"; do len=${#n); (( len > maxlen )) && maxlen=$len; done

# print
for n in "${nums[@]}"; do printf "%0*d\n" $maxlen $n; done
```

```
0000235
0000025
0000001
0963258
0000045
1356924
```