# How to add leading zeros before decimal points in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with text and numbers in it like this

```
had   hdb   hdc
1.5   -.3   4.6
2.0   7.1   .09
.17   7.4   8.9
```

So for those numbers without a leading zero before decimal points, how can I add those zeros back with a simple one line command?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width

Comment: @Chris That's different from what OP is asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use a sed substitution:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^0-9])\./\10./g' file
```

Match (and capture) the start of the line or any non-digit followed by a `.`. Replace with the captured part `\1` followed by `0.`:

```
had   hdb   hdc
1.5   -0.3   4.6
2.0   7.1   0.09
0.17   7.4   8.9
```

Answer (score 3):

Search for a decimal proceeded by a non-number and followed by a number globally (the g flag), and replace it with that same pattern (\2 part) but with a 0 in front of the decimal.

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]\|^\)\(\.[0-9]*\)/\10\2/g' input.txt
```

Output:

```
had   hdb   hdc
1.5   -0.3   4.6
2.0   7.1   0.09
0.17   7.4   8.9
```

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks Tom, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` which supports lookarounds

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)\./0./g' file 
had   hdb   hdc
1.5   -0.3   4.6
2.0   7.1   0.09
0.17   7.4   8.9
```

- `(?<!\d)\.` match `.` which is not preceded by a digit
- `0.` for such matches, add a `0` before

Answer (score 0):

As the awk `printf` modifiers are a mystery to me every time I use them, I just had to give it a go:

```
$ awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)                          # for each field
        if($i ~ /[-\.0-9]+/)                       # if looks like a number
            printf "%5.2g%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS);  # print one way
        else 
            printf "%5s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)     # else the other way
}' file
  had   hdb   hdc
  1.5  -0.3   4.6
    2   7.1  0.09
 0.17   7.4   8.9
```

The only visible flaw is `2.0` getting evened to `2` (3rd record, 1st field). Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I also tried to solve this using AWK. It is easy, if we are allowed to replace `OFS`. But what if we want to only replace the numbers in the original rows, i.e. to preserve the original spaces as much as possible?

Comment: @Ruslan the best way to preserve the structure of the individual fields and the spaces between them is not to touch them at all, i.e. to use a global substitution on the whole line. This is why I chose to use `sed` this time :)

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I solved it now with `printf` modifiers but it ain't no one-liner nor a beauty.

Comment: The OPs presumed desired output (which he hasn't shown us btw!) would be neither in %f nor %g format so converting with either of those just changes the problem since you'd still have another sub() of some kind to do afterwards. There is no canned solution using printf formatting since the OP wants their data in a non-uniform format.

Answer (score 0):

Perl version:

```
perl -pe 's/([\d\.-]+)/$1 < 1 ? $1 + 0 : $1/ge' file
```

Output:

```
had   hdb   hdc
1.5   -0.3   4.6
2.0   7.1   0.09
0.17   7.4   8.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't the first sub work on .09?

```
awk '{sub(/^\./,"0.")sub(/-/,"-0")sub(/\.09/,"0.09")}1' file

had   hdb   hdc
1.5   -0.3   4.6
2.0   7.1   0.09
0.17   7.4   8.9
```