# How can I copy a range of sequentially named files from multiple folders to one other folder?

Tags: bash

I have a directory of more than one million images, categorized according to the place the image was captured. Now theses places are again sorted alphabetically into folders. For example,

```
--- Images
        |____ a
        |     |___ airfield
        |     |___ alley
        |  
        |____ b
              |___ bank
                      |__ bank-00001.jpg
                      |__ bank-00002.jpg
                             .
                             .
                             .
```

How can I copy the first 100 files from each place subdirectory such as airfield, alley, bank etc. to a different folder ?

I have tried:

```
find /Source/Directory/path -type f  -print | tail -100 | xargs -J % cp    % /Destination/Diretory/path
```

but I am guessing it overwrote the images, because only the last 100 images of the last subfolder were copied.

My bash version

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Maybe it’s relevant to mention which version of bash are you running, `bash —version`

Comment: Edited the question to add the bash version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want them all on the same destination and all the files are named the way you have represented it:

```
               ...
                  |__ bank-00001.jpg
                  |__ bank-00002.jpg
```

You can simplify the problem by doing this:

**For versions of bash equal or above 4.0:**

```
for i in {00000001...00000100}; do
    find /path/to/Images -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*_$i.jpg" -exec cp {} /destination/path \;
done
```

This way you copy all the first 100 images on every sub-subfolder, based on their name.

**For versions of bash prior to 4.0:**

```
for i in $(seq -f '%08g' 1 100)
do
    find /path/to/Images -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*_$i.jpg" -exec cp {} /destination/path \;
done
```

[How to zero pad a sequence of integers in bash so that all have the same width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width)

Comment: My apologies, the images are named as "airfield_00000001.jpg" , "airfield_00000002.jpg" and so on. I modified the script you provided to reflect that, but I must have made an error somewhere, as the script executes for a while but the files are not copied. The modified script is
`for i in {001...100}; do
    find /Users/Ynapolean/Desktop/data_256 -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*_00000$i.jpg" -exec cp {} /Users/Ynapolean/Desktop/MITdata \;
done`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I used the updated script, I still have the same issue. The script runs but does not copy the files to the new directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for files in $(find . -type f | sed -r 's/(.*\/).*$/\1/g' | uniq); 
do 
    find ${files} -type f | head -n100 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 cp /path/where/to/copy; 
done
```

Im not sure if it's correctly, have no linux-terminal near. The logic is: 
1) Find uniq full paths to your files. 
2) Run in loop, search files in each directory, get with `head -n100` first 100 files, copy them with xargs

Comment: The `-r` option is illegal apparently, perhaps its not available on a mac ?

Comment: I've seen mac's sed is not the same as linux's sed. So I'm not sure I'll be able to help you with this question.

Comment: @YeshwanthNapolean use `-E` then.