# ¿How to iterate PostalCodes in Spain with bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to iterate a sequence of numbers , the postal codes in Spain is from 01001 to 52080 and I have the following code.

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=01001; c<=52080; c++ ))
do  
    echo "$c"
done
```

But I have a problem , I need to add a 0 when the length of the numbers are four.

How can I do this ?

```
{
      "countryName" : "Spain" ,
      "numPostalCodes" : 37866 ,
      "countryCode" : "ES" ,
      "maxPostalCode" : "52080" ,
      "minPostalCode" : "01001"
    }
```

Regards !

Comment: You can do this with the `printf` builtin. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width) for more info.

Comment: Correct , sorry for the question I can delete the question if you want.

Comment: It's actually helpful to have a question phrased in different ways, as long as each question points to the same set of answers. This will probably get closed as a duplicate. In the meantime, I'm glad you have found your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf "%05d\n" "$c"
```