# Multiple brace expansion in wget URL

Tags: linux, bash, wget, brace-expansion

I am currently trying to scrape images of a website with a little script I've made :

```
for url in $my_url/{1..100}'.png' 
do
    wget "$url" || break
done
```

The fast is that sometimes, images are named 1.png or 01.png or 001.png

So I would like to try the download of the images with each name to not miss any pictures.

Something like :

```
for url in $my_url/{1..100}{01..100}{001..100}'.png'
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping everything in a for loop that creates multiple zero-padding formats:

```
for format in %01g %02g %03g
  do for num in $(seq -f $format 1 100)
    do wget ${my_url}/${num}.png || break  
  done  
done
```

You could also use printf, but would need to use different syntax, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width).

Answer (score 1):

You need to duplicate them:

```
for url in "$my_url"/{1..100}.png "$my_url"/{01..100}.png "$my_url"/{001..100}.png
```

or,  using an array aids readability

```
urls=( 
    "$my_url"/{1..100}.png 
    "$my_url"/{01..100}.png 
    "$my_url"/{001..100}.png
)
for url in "${urls[@]}"; do ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest brace expansions:

```
url="http://example.com/"
printf '%s\n' "$url"{{0..9},{00..99},{000..100}}.png
```