# Adding padded zeros to name files

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, printf, seq

Based off this: [How to zero pad a sequence of integers in bash so that all have the same width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width)

I need to create new file names to enter into an array representing chromosomes 1-22 with three digits (chromsome001_results_file.txt..chromsome022_results_file.txt)

Prior to using a three digit system (which sorts easier) I was using

```
for i in {1..22}; 
do echo chromsome${i}_results_file.txt; 
done
```

I have read about printf and seq but was wondering how they could be put within the middle of a loop surrounded by text to get the 001 to 022 to stick to the text.

Many thanks

Comment: `for i in {001..022}; do`

Comment: the question you link to is enough information to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` specifying a field with and zero padding.

```
for i in {1..22}; 
do 
    printf 'chromsome%03d_results_file.txt\n' "$i"
done
```

In `%03d`, `d` means decimal output,  `3` means 3 digits, and `0` means zero padding.