# find missing files in a very long list where files are numbered sequentially

Tags: bash, list, directory, sequential, largenumber

I have a directory which has more than 330000 files and unfortunately I cannot use `ls`.
In order to list them I use `find` and I have printed the output in a file [list of files](https://filebin.net/lwpckmoz881sou9q)

These files are named sequentially, therefore there is a long list that goes Blast0_1.txt.gz Blast0_2.txt.gz Blast0_3.txt.gz....

and these numbers go up to 587, hence the total of the files should 588x588=345744 (because numbering for both before and after the underscore starts at 0

There are some combinations that are missing, because the total should be 345744 but unfortunately it is 331357.
Is there an easy way to find the missing combinations through bash? I saw that there are available some solutions online but they do not work for me and I cannot figure how to adapt any of them in my dataset.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through all possible filenames and check whether the file exists. On my laptop, this took around 8 seconds for 588x588 combinations.

```sh
for i in {0..588}; do
    for j in {0..588}; do
        file_name="Blast${i}_${j}.txt.gz"
        [ ! -f $file_name ] && echo "$file_name"
    done
done
```

This will go through all possible combinations, check whether the file exists and if not, print its filename to the console.

Depending on your naming scheme, you might have to [zero pad the numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/how-to-zero-pad-a-sequence-of-integers-in-bash-so-that-all-have-the-same-width).